# What is the difference between xeus-python and ipython?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab, xeus-python

[`JupyterLab 3.0`](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-3-0-is-out-4f58385e25bb) comes with a full-fledged [`visual debugger`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html). But using it is only posssible if you're running a [`xeus-python`](https://xeus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) kernel. Other sources report that there are a few differences between `xeus-python` and `ipython`, but that the list of [features that differ](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-get-ready-to-ditch-the-ipython-kernel-54d60776d7ef) between the two is shrinking. So that's not really what I'm asking for here. Rather, what is it that distinguishes `xeus-python` from `ipython` that makes it suitable for a visual debugger as the one featured by `JupyterLab 3.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rather, what is it that distinguishes xeus-python from ipython that makes it suitable for a visual debugger as the one featured by JupyterLab 3.0?

It's nothing particularly deep or interesting. Jupyter defines a [debugger protocol](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#debug-request) that's a straightforward wrapper around the [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/). Kernels have to support this protocol to be usable with the JupyterLab debugger.

xeus-python supports this protocol. The IPython kernel does not. They're working on it; I *think* it's planned for IPython kernel 6.0 (not to be confused with IPython 6.0, which came out a while ago).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any sources on that last part by any chance?

Comment: @vestland: [Here's a recent issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/629) showing it not quite working yet on IPython kernel 6.0.0a2, marked Milestone: 6.0.