# how to run debugger in anaconda jupyter lab notebook

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, visual-studio-debugging, jupyter-lab

I installed anaconda
I don't know how to run visual debugger in jupyter lab or jupyter notebook
and what is the difference between them ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjaTu.png)

Comment: Please try to ask only one question at a time. The difference between notebook and lab is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982686/what-is-the-difference-between-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterlab (though the answers are a bit dated). IMO JupyterLab is the way to go now.

Comment: In short, you will need to install a kernel that supports debugging, e.g. xeus-python (`conda -c conda-forge xeus-python`). I will now tag your question as a duplicate of another question where you will find more answers so that users who find this question can quickly find the other one which has more answers. Hope that it helps!

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082539/what-is-the-difference-between-xeus-python-and-ipython